# Showing R is Sequential

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

I want to prove rigorously that R is sequential.

Sequential means that every sequentially open set is open (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space).

I can understand intuitively why R is sequential but I have trouble with rigorous proof-writing.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show that $\Bbb R$ is second-countable? Every second-countable space is sequential assuming the axiom of countable choice.

Comment: I can prove that R is second-countable, sure.  Can you show me exactly how that proves that it is sequential?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U\subseteq\Bbb R$ be a sequentially-open set. That is for all sequences $\{x_k\}$ such that there is an $x\in U$ and $x_k\rightarrow x$, then there is an $N\in\Bbb N$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we have $x_n\in U$.

Suppose for contradiction that $U$ is not open. That means, there is an $x\in U$ such that $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$ is not contained in $U$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

Consider the collection of neighborhoods $(x-1/n, x+1/n)$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. By assumption, there is an $r_n\in (x-1/n, x+1/n)$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. By appealing to countable choice, we can construct a sequence $\{r_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $r_n\in (x-1/n, x+1/n)\setminus U$ for all $n$. Clearly $r_n\rightarrow x$, however by construction, $r_n\not\in U$ for all $n$ which contradicts that $U$ is sequentially open.

This proof generalizes to an arbitrary second-countable space, where for a given point you take the collection of all basis elements which contain that point and 'refine' them to be nested like here where we have a sequence of nested neighborhoods.

Comment: Ah, ok I see thank you.  I can just say "By appealing to the axiom of countable choice" and assume that in a proof, correct?

Comment: Most properties of the real numbers that are proven in a real analysis course are equivalent to the claim that countable choice holds for all countable collections of subsets of $\Bbb R$. As such it usually isn't explicitly appealed to. If you ever see "we can construct a sequence such that..." that's the typical flag some form of choice is being used.

Comment: @Jimmy jfyi: that every subspace of $\Bbb R$ is a sequential space is equivalent to the claim that countable choice holds for all countable collections of nonempty subsets of $\Bbb R$. Another claim which is equivalent is that $\Bbb R$ is a Frechet-Urysohn space. More interesting details can be found here: http://www.mat.uc.pt/~ggutc/teses/teseingles.pdf